# React: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having problem rendering a route in React. All I see is the page before React does any rendering to it, and the following error.

Mainly, I'm having trouble figuring out which component/line is causing the error, if anyone can provide some insight I'd appreciate that. Thanks.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Without the relevant code there's not much we can do. Only thing is sure, `object` in `object._currentElement` is `null`.

Comment: Here is a bug writeup that is probably your issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4026

Comment: Any error you're getting apart from this, maybe some other issue is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're importing all components your using inside your `render() { ... }` block.

This error can be thrown if you're trying to render a component that hasn't been properly imported or is returning `undefined`.

If this is a case you may also be seeing a related error `Uncaught TypeError: inst.render is not a function`.

I try to identifying which component is causing the issue by:

- Replace jsx with simple `<div>test</div>` element by element
- If I find an element / component causing it, I make sure it is impoted, then dig deeper.
- Look at your diff and revert code / stash code

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had such error when had multiple instances of `React` required. Is it the case for you?

Comment: I noticed that there are two Router element inside Top Level tag, but I have no idea where it was included.

Answer (score 0):

I frequently see this after *any* component has let an uncaught exception out of its `render()` method. Only resolution we've found so far is refreshing the page.

The React GitHub issue @JosiahDaniels linked ([#4026](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4026)) discusses the same behavior: "Some invariant violations leaves React in an unstable state at the moment so this is to be expected." --`syranide`

The issue is closed, as the onus is on the application author not to disrupt React's rendering cycle with exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could forget exporting the component:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
   ...
});

module.exports = MyComponent;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

React v15 added an unstable_handleError function, which can be used to help troubleshoot this sort of issue.

Basic example:

```
  unstable_handleError = (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  }
```

More info:
https://medium.com/@blairanderson/handle-react-errors-in-v15-4cedaae757d7#.9moxc4d3z